# Spring Boot Actuator Health Returning DOWN

Tags: spring-boot

When I access the `/health` endpoint from my Spring Boot application (1.2.4.RELEASE) it is returning a status of `DOWN`:

```
{
    status: "DOWN"
}
```

Are there any starter projects or libraries that are known to overwrite the status?  Is there any other reason (besides writing a custom one) why it would return `DOWN`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In your Spring properties, set `endpoints.health.sensitive = false`. The `/health` endpoint will then return the list of various health indicators and you can debug from there.

For a production environment you should enable security around the `/health` endpoint.

**Edit**

As Vincent pointed out below, you'll also need `management.security.enabled = false` if the health endpoint is secured, which seems to be the default in more recent versions of Spring Boot.

A common issue that I've seen with Spring Boot out of the box is that it auto-configures Solr, and without additional configuration the `/health` endpoint indicates that Solr is `DOWN`. An easy way to fix this is to disable the Solr auto configuration in your Application.java with this annotation:

`@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SolrAutoConfiguration.class})`

Comment: Is there a way to keep the sensitive to false, so that in production would not see what exactly is down, but also log the actual status of every component so that is the service is "DOWN" I can check the logs and see what's going on?

Comment: Good point on Solr, however easier way to disable it would be using the property: management.health.solr.enabled=true

Answer (score 37):

If the health url shows "DOWN" or HTTP 503 - Service Unavailable error, then try adding the below property in ***application.properties***

URL - [http://localhost:8080/actuator/health](http://HOST:PORT/actuator/health)

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Now the url should show more than just DOWN. 
If Solr host is not reachable, then ignore the Solr check using the below exclusion -

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SolrAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Now the health should come up. The health check basically validates predefined health check internally (Example - `DataSourceHealthIndicator, DiskSpaceHealthIndicator, CassandraHealthIndicator`, etc).

If one of the health indicator is down, the health will be down and you can see the error as a response after adding the property mentioned above to ***application.properties.***

Comment: management.endpoint.health.show-details=always is a nice one, it actually shows which section of the service is down so that you can take appropriate action.

Comment: Thank you. The property as the property name suggests details the health check status! Very helpful!

Comment: In my case it was spring-ldap-core that had to be excluded.

Answer (score 22):

in my case, I needed **both** these properties to get more details :

```
endpoints.health.sensitive: false
management.security.enabled: false
```

Otherwise, all I was getting was an DOWN status.

I had an issue with RabbitMQ connection : my application is not using it yet, but we've started wiring some code related to it. The application works fine, but we were getting DOWN health status, which was quite puzzling : Spring Boot is surprisingly silent in the logs, as no error shows at startup (I'll probably need to change my config to make it more verbose)

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue with Springboot 2.1.0 where /actuator/health returned
`{
status: "DOWN"
}`
even though application was up. 
Adding 
`management.health.defaults.enabled=false` 
to properties file fixed the issue.

Comment: This removes all the other information, so it wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 4):

You guy are probably using Consul 1.0. There is a known issue in Spring Could Consul 1.1.0 or so with Consul 1.0. See this - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/365 and this - https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/3635

You will have to upgrade to Spring Could Consul 1.3.0.RELEASE.

Answer (score 2):

As per this link : https://github.com/indrabasak/spring-consul-example/blob/master/client/README.md, we should strictly used below properties to avoid below error.

```
management.security.enabled=false
management.health.consul.enabled=false
```

[image]

Comment: The health down status due to consul health check failure in Springboot application was resolved with your suggestion management.health.consul.enabled=false

Answer (score 1):

If you just added endpoint and it is down check maybe something of default checks is down see the [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#_auto_configured_healthindicators) to see what is checked by default. in my case I forgot to run elastic, so health-check reported "down" as Rashmi pointed out you can disable defaults by `management.health.defaults.enabled=false`, but it is better to find the actual reason why

Answer (score 1):

management.endpoint.health.show-details=, it always help to debug why the Health is DOWN , it helped me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed using below code.

Wrote a controller which accepts "/private/health" mapping (You can use /health instead).

```
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping
@Api(value = "Heath Service Health", description = "Heath Service Health")
public class HeathController {
  @GetMapping(value = "/private/health")
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  HealthStatusDto healthCheck() {
    return HealthStatusDto.builder().status("UP").build();
  }
}
```

Below class is optional. Instead of returning HealthStatusDto in above controller you can return any other message as a String.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public final class HealthStatusDto {
  private final String status;
}
```

Add below config in application.yml

```
# actuator
# Disable Spring security
management:
  security:
    enabled: false

# Disable actuators
endpoints:
  actuator:
    enabled: false
  enabled: false
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I built a filter to log the health response when it fails.

```java
package br.gov.go.sspj.k9.util;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class BadHealthCheckLogFilter implements Filter {

  private @Autowired HealthMvcEndpoint hme;

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    if (req.getRequestURI().endsWith("/health") && res.getStatus() != 200)
      log.error(hme.invoke(req, null).toString());
  }

  @Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
  }

  @Override
  public void destroy() {
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually did the same - downlside is, that the healthcheck is invoked twice (might be a performance issue with custom HealthChecks).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I upgraded an application from spring boot 1.5 to 2.3.5.RELEASE.

Adding `endpoints.health.sensitive` and other properties as mentioned in other answers to `application.properties` didn't work for me.

I fixed the issue by excluding `RabbitAutoConfiguration`.

`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { RabbitAutoConfiguration.class })`

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot 2.3.2 and above just adding

1. `management.health.defaults.enabled=false` solved my issue.
2. Hitting the same API with `/management/health` now return "UP"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Spring (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

endpoints.actuator.enabled=true
management.health.defaults.enabled=false

adding above properties solved my issue .

giving status "UP"

Answer (score 0):

Setting the following configuration help me troubleshoot the problem

`management.endpoint.health.show-details=always`

In my case, the antivirus application is blocking connection to my mail server. Turn it off solved problem